# Efficiently copy Matrix (such as opencv cv::Mat, realsense rs2::frame) to Eigen::Matrix

Tags: opencv, matrix, eigen, data-conversion, realsense

I am working on the data conversion from opencv cv::Mat or realsense rs2::frame to Eigen::Matrix.
Is there an efficient way to do this conversion?
For example:

```
//For opencv Mat:
cv::Mat cvMat = cv::Mat::zeros(100, 100, CV_8UC1);
unsigned char* cv_data = cvMat.data();

Eigen::Matrix<unsigned char, 100, 100> eigenMat;
unsigned char* eigen_data = eigenMat.data();

//use memcpy
memcpy(eigen_data, cv_data, 100*100*sizeof(unsigned char));
```

However, `Eigen::Matrix` has memory alignement. Is it correct to use `memcpy` directly?
Or I have to use a `for` loop to assign each element of `cvMat` to `eigenMat`?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try compiling the code?

Comment: I have compiled this code. However, if I convert `cvMat` to `eigenMat`, `eigenMat` is the transpose of `cvMat`. Is `eigenMat` column major while `cvMat` row major?

Comment: You can specify storage order in Eigen as `RowMajor` or `ColMajor`. Forexample `Matrix<int, 3, 4, ColMajor> Acolmajor;`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that if the storage order of opencv Mat and realsense rs2::frame is different. If I specify the storage order of Eigen::Matrix, it is not convenient to convert them.

Comment: I don't understand you are trying to convert what into what?

Comment: For example, I use realsense camera. Realsense provides an SDK for developers. The SDK has their datastructure `rs2::frame`. I need to convert such structure to Eigen::Matrix for processing. So that I need to convert them efficiently.